# What does this RPC error message mean?

Tags: linux, rhel6, nfs

I have OS RHNL release 6.2 and use the NFS service (nfs-utils-1.2.3) to connect to NFS server,

And found a lot of messages in a file /var/log/messages:

```
Apr  1 11:08:35 XXX  rpc.idmapd[3010]: nss_getpwnam: name '2' does not map into domain 'XXXX.com'
Apr  1 11:14:26 XXX  rpc.idmapd[3010]: nss_getpwnam: name '0' does not map into domain 'XXXX.com'
Apr  1 11:18:36 XXX  rpc.idmapd[3010]: nss_getpwnam: name '2' does not map into domain 'XXXX.com'
Apr  1 11:24:27 XXX  rpc.idmapd[3010]: nss_getpwnam: name '0' does not map into domain 'XXXX.com'
Apr  1 11:28:37 XXX  rpc.idmapd[3010]: nss_getpwnam: name '2' does not map into domain 'XXXX.com'
Apr  1 11:34:27 XXX  rpc.idmapd[3010]: nss_getpwnam: name '0' does not map into domain 'XXXX.com'
Apr  1 11:38:37 XXX  rpc.idmapd[3010]: nss_getpwnam: name '2' does not map into domain 'XXXX.com'
Apr  1 11:44:28 XXX  rpc.idmapd[3010]: nss_getpwnam: name '0' does not map into domain 'XXXX.com'
Apr  1 11:48:37 XXX  rpc.idmapd[3010]: nss_getpwnam: name '2' does not map into domain 'XXXX.com'
```

What does this message mean ?

Answer (score 1):

it means you have a hostname issue in your /etc/idmapd.conf file or in your /etc/hosts file. Make sure your idmapd.conf file is the same on both the NFS server and client, also make sure that your client is resolving localhost and localdomain to the loopback address (127.0.0.1) and your domain name is not resolving to the loopback.